# "float" object not iretable error; but I dont see what I'm iterating over?

Tags: python

I am trying to rewrite fast5 (HDF5) data files into abf format, I have the following code that should be able to rewrite the given fast5 file into an general data type for rewrite into abf with another tool. However the code below produces errors at the digitizing step

```
from uuid import uuid4
import numpy as np
from fast5_research import BulkFast5

filename='test1.fast5'
mean, stdv, n = 40.0, 2.0, 10000
raw_data = np.random.laplace(mean, stdv/np.sqrt(2))


# example of how to digitize data
start, stop = int(min(raw_data - 1)), int(max(raw_data + 1))
rng = stop - start
digitisation = 8192.0
bins = np.arange(start, stop, rng / digitisation)


# np.int16 is required, the library will refuse to write anything other
raw_data = np.digitize(raw_data, bins).astype(np.int16)



# The following are required meta data
channel_id = {
    'digitisation': digitisation,
    'offset': 0,
    'range': rng,
    'sampling_rate': 4000,
    'channel_number': 1,
    }
read_id = {
    'start_time': 0,
    'duration': len(raw_data),
    'read_number': 1,
    'start_mux': 1,
    'read_id': str(uuid4()),
    'scaling_used': 1,
    'median_before': 0,
}
tracking_id = {
    'exp_start_time': '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    'run_id': str(uuid4()).replace('-',''),
    'flow_cell_id': 'FAH00000',
}
context_tags = {}

with Fast5.New(filename, 'w', tracking_id=tracking_id, context_tags=context_tags, channel_id=channel_id) as h:
    h.set_raw(raw_data, meta=read_id, read_number=1)
```

with error

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py:13: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import fnmatch, glob, traceback, errno, sys, atexit, locale, imp, stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/archie/PycharmProjects/Fast5read/Fast5rewrite.py", line 11, in <module>
    start, stop = int(min(raw_data - 1)), int(max(raw_data + 1))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

When I looked for help I am suppose to iterate over a range, but I dont see where the iteration is or how to fix this error than.

Comment: `raw_data` is a `float`, how can you take `min` of that? I think you forgot to pass `n` how many samples you wanted to draw `np.random.laplace(mean, stdv/np.sqrt(2), n)`

Comment: My understanding was that the `np.random.laplace(mean, stdv/np.sqrt(2))` would be iretable but I was not aware that the min and max iterated over them anyway. I do not know to be honest what second argument to feed into those calls.

Comment: @AbhjeetBhullar In addition to `mean` and `stdv/np.sqrt(2)` you should also pass `n` so it will return an array of `n` sampled elements

Comment: Cory Kramer you were absolutely correct, Thank you so much I cant believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

```
start, stop = int(min(raw_data - 1)), int(max(raw_data + 1))
```

`min()` and `max()` are functions that expect to take iterables as arguments. They find the smallest and largest element in those iterables respectively.

Given the way you've called `np.random.laplace()`, it will return a single float value back, which is not an iterable.

Comment: Given they have `n = 10000` above, I *think* the real fix would be their call to `laplace` to be `raw_data = np.random.laplace(mean, stdv/np.sqrt(2), n)` so that they have an array of sampled values. But your answer is still valid obviously.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an iterable from `numpy.random.laplace` you must specify the shape of the array you want returning in the (optional) 3rd parameter.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.laplace.html

e.g. to draw 10000 samples:

```
mean, stdv, n = 40.0, 2.0, 10000
raw_data = np.random.laplace(mean, stdv/np.sqrt(2),n)
    
# example of how to digitize data
start, stop = int(min(raw_data - 1)), int(max(raw_data + 1))
rng = stop - start
digitisation = 8192.0
bins = np.arange(start, stop, rng / digitisation)
```